# How to render a list of components held as a key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following list of React components and can't change this format.

How could I render this list on my page by looping over it in some way?

```
  const allComponents = isValid => [
    {
      Component: (
        <ComponentA
          isTransparent={true}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      Component: (
        <div>
          {<ComponentB/>}
        </div>
      ),
    },
    !isValid && {
      Component: (
        <div>
          {<ComponentC/>}
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ].filter(Boolean);
```

Within my return block tried the following:

```
  return (
      <Fragment>
          {allComponents(false).map(c => (
            {c}
          ))}
      </Fragment>
  );
```

End up with following error.

> Error! Objects are not valid as a React child.
> (found: object with keys {c}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

But the above allComponents is an array.

Could I please get some advice on this pls.

Comment: @pilchard c.Component throws  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected . The unexpected token is the dot (.) . Totally agree on the structure being cumbersome. But having to stick with this format cos it is in use in another external component which takes in this exact format as a prop. Trying not to have to duplicate / modify the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSX stored in the the array returned by `allComponents()` needs to be returned from a valid function component. You can either turn the `Component` properties into functions

```
    {
      Component: () => (
        <ComponentA />
      ),
    },

    // And then call it in the map()
    {allComponents(false).map(c => (
        c.Component()
    ))}
```

or return the JSX from an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) inside the `map()` call

```
    {allComponents(false).map(c => (
        (() => c.Component)()
    ))}
```

Working snippet

```js
const App = () => {
  const allComponents = isValid => [
    {
      Component: (
        <ComponentA />
      )
      ,
    },
    {
      Component: (
        <div>
          {<ComponentB />}
        </div>
      )
      ,
    },
    !isValid && {
      Component: (
        <div>
          {<ComponentC />}
        </div>)
      ,
    },
  ].filter(Boolean);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>isValid: False</p>
      <div>
        {allComponents(false).map(c => (
          (() => c.Component)()
        ))}
      </div>
      <p>isValid: True</p>
      <div>
        {allComponents(true).map(c => (
          (() => c.Component)()
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <div>Component A</div>
  )
}
const ComponentB = () => {
  return (
    <div>Component B</div>
  )
}
const ComponentC = () => {
  return (
    <div>Component C</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  return (
      <Fragment>
          {allComponents(false).map(c => (
            {c.component}
          ))}
      </Fragment>
  );
```

you are attempting to render an object in your above example and not the component itself.  IMO I would update your overall structure

Comment: c.Component throws error => Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected . The unexpected token is the dot (.) .